# iOS - Instruments Zombie detection not helping

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, zombie-process

I am facing a problem in Tracing the cause of Exception. The applciation crashes with the message

```
    `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: [<ExpandingGridViewController 0x7574760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key gridView.
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ec2012 0x12ffe7e 0x1f4afb1 0xbd5e41 0xb575f8 0xb570e7 0xb81b58 0x28b019 0x1313663 0x1ebd45a 0x289b1c 0x14e7e7 0x14edc8 0x14eff8 0x14f232 0x44c5 0xabd66 0xab753 0xb81cc 0x60af 0x38b0 0x3156 0xfb50 0x10e46 0xb275b3 0x1e81376 0x1e80e06 0x1e68a82 0x1e67f44 0x1e67e1b 0x1e1c7e3 0x1e1c668 0x6dffc 0x2535 0x2435)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`
```

I have tried detecting Zombies using Instruments but of no use.

[image: How i set Zombie Detection]

and after the application crashes there is not trace of any Zombie in the **Instruments**.

[image]

What else should be done to detect the reasons of the crash?

Comment: `NSUnknownKeyException` is unlikely to be an error that is caught by Instruments' zombie detection. Can you repeat the error in the debugger? If so, just look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is doing a `setValue:<some object> forKey:@"gridView"` - probably Interface Builder has a view set to that, but that property is no longer in your .m file.

Failing that, do a global search on your project and find all occurrences of `gridView`, and add an assert in front of each that the object receiving that message has a property `gridView`.

Comment: Yup, looks like an old IBOutlet connection whose property got removed, rather than a zombies problem.

Comment: Yup that worked. At least i reached EXC_BAD_EXCESS exception. Thanks Man .